# Minecraft Sleeping Problem

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have this one world on Minecraft, and it’s survival. The problem is that every time I go to bed (at night) it says “Morgana is happy with your decision”. Who is Morgana? I tried searching up the name and the problem with Minecraft and nothing comes up. Also, when I try sleeping in the day it says, “Morgana does not want you to sleep right now”. I would really appreciate it if someone could explain this to me. The world does have a resource pack, but I read into it and the pack hasn’t edited any text.

Comment: Wow, what a weird question. Only resource packs, mods or commands can do that. One of these must be present.

Comment: https://mcpedl.com/sketchy-world-pack/#comment-224448 Looks like another person is having this problem

Comment: I cannot test it right now, but I am pretty sure it has something to do with Phantoms

Comment: Is it the sketchy world resource pack? Cause that resource pack has Morgana is happy with your decision and etc in it

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a resource pack or mod has been installed. If it's a resource pack, then you should be able to go into the resource pack list and turn it off. If it's a mod, I wouldn't have the slightest idea how to uninstall it, but there are probably multiple tutorials on the Internet willing to tell you.

About that resource pack you might think isn't doing it, try turning it off and going to sleep. If it changes back, keep it off. If it doesn't try looking for mods that might be causing this problem.